# How to Get count of rows on multiple where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have a table.

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════╦═════════════╦══════╦═══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ StockiestCode ║ ClientID ║ ProductName ║ Sale ║ TranDate  ║ CompanyProductID ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 453           ║ 254      ║ Almiron     ║ 12   ║ 8/18/2019 ║ NULL             ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 453           ║ 254      ║ Zenflox     ║ 14   ║ 8/18/2019 ║ NULL             ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 453           ║ 254      ║ Almiron     ║ 15   ║ 8/18/2019 ║ NULL             ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 457           ║ 258      ║ Zenflox     ║ 19   ║ 8/18/2019 ║ 1                ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 457           ║ 258      ║ Almiron     ║ 12   ║ 8/18/2019 ║ 2                ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 457           ║ 258      ║ Zenflox     ║ 13   ║ 8/18/2019 ║ 1                ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 457           ║ 258      ║ Almiron     ║ 14   ║ 8/18/2019 ║ 2                ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 453           ║ 254      ║ Almiron     ║ 12   ║ 7/18/2019 ║ NULL             ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 453           ║ 254      ║ Zenflox     ║ 14   ║ 7/18/2019 ║ NULL             ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 453           ║ 254      ║ Almiron     ║ 15   ║ 7/18/2019 ║ NULL             ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 457           ║ 258      ║ Zenflox     ║ 19   ║ 7/18/2019 ║ 1                ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 457           ║ 258      ║ Almiron     ║ 12   ║ 7/18/2019 ║ 2                ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 457           ║ 258      ║ Zenflox     ║ 13   ║ 7/18/2019 ║ 1                ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 457           ║ 258      ║ Almiron     ║ 14   ║ 7/18/2019 ║ 2                ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════╩═════════════╩══════╩═══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

In which i want an output of Below.

```
╔════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Month  ║ Count Of Stockiest Code ║ Count Of ClientID where Company Product ID ║
║        ║                         ║   is not null                              ║
╠════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Jul-19 ║ 2                       ║ 1                                          ║
╠════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Aug-19 ║ 2                       ║ 1                                          ║
╚════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I tried writing this query but wasn't successfull.

```
SELECT Date_format(A.tran_date, '%Y-%m'), 
       Count(DISTINCT A.stockist_code), 
       Count(DISTINCT B.client_id) 
FROM   ferring_updated.zsecondarysales AS A 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Date_format(tran_date, '%Y-%m') AS 'TranDate', 
                          client_id 
                   FROM   ferring_updated.zsecondarysales 
                   WHERE  companyproduct_id IS NOT NULL) AS B 
               ON Date_format(A.tran_date, '%Y-%m') = B.trandate 
GROUP  BY Date_format(A.tran_date, '%Y-%m');
```

First i want to group by Month and the second column would be count of stockiest codes and the third column would be count of Client ID where Company Product is not null and the group by month.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to do a conditional aggregation

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TranDate,'%Y-%m') AS month,
       COUNT(DISTINCT StockiestCode) AS StockiestCodeCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN CompanyProductID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ClientID END)) AS ClientIDCount
  FROM ZSecondarySales
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TranDate,'%Y-%m')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af3c3e/7)

```
|   month | StockiestCodeCount | ClientIDCount |
|---------|--------------------|---------------|
| 2019-07 |                  2 |             1 |
| 2019-08 |                  2 |             1 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! @peterm. That worked like a champ :-)

Comment: @ShahabHaidar You're very welcome! I'm glad it helped :)